# Difficulty creating navbar toggle with django-bootstrap3

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, navbar

I would like to add a simple navbar to my site using [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3).  The base.html document I am editing to create the navbar works with Twitter Bootstrap but does not with django-bootstrap3.  The issue I am having is the button that is supposed to toggle the drop-down does not do anything when clicked.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Here is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>

{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
</style>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

 <!------Navbar ---------->

<header class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role = "banner">
<div class = "container">
    <div class ="navbar-header">
        <button type = "button" class= "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#dropdown">
            <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="#" class ="navbar-brand">Project Name</a>
    </div><!-- End Navbar Header-->

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "dropdown">

        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role = "navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Page</a></li>
        </ul>      

    </div><!-- End Nav Contents -->
</div><!-- End Container -->
</header>
```

Comment: You might have some issue with where your static files are being looked for.  Look at your settings.py to be sure that makes sense.  Also, look at the source code to the html to see if something isn't getting accessed.

Comment: when accessing base.html look at your terminal log.. Any disturbance..?

Comment: There are no disturbances.  I have been reading through the documentation and it does not have anything written about data toggling or data-targets unfortunately.  I do not see any issues in my settings.py file and everything else has been rendered just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that django-bootstrap3's javascript needs jquery installed (I had wrongfully assumed django-bootstrap3 did this automatically).  As soon as I referenced jquery the problem was fixed immediately.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you referenced jquery correctly? I am having a very similar issue.

Comment: The default settings for django-bootstrap3 is to not include jquery loads.  So you can either add the link to load jquery, or change the default settings.  Take a look @ https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html.  Specifically,     # Include jQuery with Bootstrap JavaScript (affects django-bootstrap3 template tags)
    'include_jquery': True,

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is 2 years old but in case for everyone having the same issue in the futur, here the solution: in your template, replace:

```
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

By:

```
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery=1 %}
```